# Create and manage a group using the Facebook API

Tags: facebook

I am new to Facebook application development and I am looking for a way to create and manage a group using the the Facebook API. There is a get and get list call but I have not found a way to manage groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of writing there is no method of the Facebook API for creating groups. Methods are however available to get the details of specific groups.

For more information see the API docs,

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/API

Comment: I wish this were wrong but I am becoming to believe it is true also.

Comment: The link appears to be broken.  Can you find the new home of the API? (I'd do it, but I don't use Facebook, and Google keeps taking me to pages where they're asking me to log in.)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the API has been released:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/app-game-groups/

Comment: Is this available in any way for regular groups?

Comment: this is available for anyone to post/read to facebook groups, if you have permission from the user.  You can create/delete groups by using the app token.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook says developers will also be able to create Groups and manage Group membership via the API “in the near future.”

(11 Oct 2010) http://www.insidefacebook.com/2010/10/11/groups-api-details-apotential/

Comment: I'd sure like to know what Facebook considers the "near future"... I don't think they define that the same way as the rest of us.

Comment: 11/16 and still no way to manage groups with the API.. even basic functions.. or even list posts by date.